# Not able send mail on test failure: Maven

Tags: maven, email, testing, report, appium

Using surefire plugin and postman plugin, I am able to send email with attachment to a recipient if test case passes. On test case failure i am getting following error. I don't know what I am missing. Please help.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project FSmaven1: There are test failures.

```
    </project><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ymedia</groupId>
  <artifactId>FSmaven1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FSmaven1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uttesh</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfngreport</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build> 
        <plugins>
        <!-- Suirefire plugin to run xml files --> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Post-Man plugin -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                <id>send a mail</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                <goal>send-mail</goal>
                </goals>
                <inherited>true</inherited>

                <configuration>
                    <!-- From Email address -->
                    <from>XXX</from>

                    <!--  Email subject -->
                    <subject>Test Automation Report</subject>

                    <!-- Fail the build if the mail doesnt reach -->
                    <failonerror>false</failonerror>

                    <!-- host -->
                    <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost>
                    <!-- port of the host -->
                    <mailport>465</mailport>
                    <mailssl>true</mailssl>
                    <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>

                    <!-- Email Authentication(USername and Password) -->
                    <mailuser>xxx</mailuser>
                    <mailpassword>xxx</mailpassword>

                    <receivers>
                        <!-- To Email address -->
                        <receiver>xxx</receiver>
                    </receivers>

                    <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <!-- Report directory Path -->
                        <directory>./reports</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <!-- Report file name -->
                            <include>*.pdf</include>
                        </includes>
                        <!-- Use Regular Expressions like **/*.html if you want all the html files to send-->
                        </fileSet>
                    </fileSets>             

                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Sending mail is a task for a CI solution like Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [Maven Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) to your build. It allows for safe execution in case of test failures. Let us know if that worked for you.

**Edit 1** Can you also try adding `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>` to your Surefire plugin configuration?

Comment: i have added Maven Failsafe plugin to my pom.xml file. still Build is failing if yet case fails. 
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version><configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>

     <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

Comment: Thanks for you help. It worked for after using this cmd: mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven execution is never reaching the mail sending plugin because there are test failures. Add these lines in maven-surefire-plugin's configuration section :

```
 <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>   
 <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

That should solve your problems.